# TF31002 Can't connect to TFS 2010 from VS 2012 or from the browser

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, credentialscache

My machine runs windows 7 (Workgroup) and i am using Windows  Visual Studio 2012 (Utltimate Version 11, Update 4) to connect to TFS 2010 on a domain server.

Recently, i was working normally (my PC was related to different domain, i changed it because all PCs on the network are related to workgroup and not complaining) connecting to TFS and doing my casual work.

Today I am not able to connect neither from **VS** nor from the **Web**. 
Trying to connect from VS 2012 using my:

1. PC Account: **USER_A** and
2. TFS Account: TFS_USER

displays this **Error**:

---

F31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: 'Your TFS Server'. 
Team Foundation Server Url: 'Your TFS Server URL'.

Possible reasons for failure include:

- The Team Foundation Server name, port number or protocol is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- Password is expired or incorrect.

---

### Scenarios Tried Out

I have tried the following to fix the problem:

1. Cleared the cache C:\Users[my user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
2. Cleared the cache of TFS V 3.0 as above
3. Cleared the internet Explorer cache and Cookies using Internet Options
4. Remove all the saved credentials from Control Panel -> Credential Manager
5. I have reset my user account password for the TFS account

### Successful Attempt

I have logged in using different account into my PC

1. PC Account: **USER_B** then
2. TFS Account: TFS_USER

It worked normally!

How can i fix the Problem?

Comment: Because you can connect to TFS with the same TFS_USER on the same machine, there is nothing wrong with TFS server and the TFS_USER account has the required permissions to access TFS. And from your description, it seems that you get this error because of the USER_A account you used to log on PC. So, any further information on USER_A? Is it an account in a different or same domain as TFS?

Comment: USER_A is a member of the Administrators group, on the local PC. But also it was a user on the domain DEV.com (since the PC was joined to the domain) .The TFS Server is joined to domain Web.Dev.Com  Noting that,  I removed my PC from the domain after the error appears.